# How openbox knows .bash_aliases used in its autostart file

Tags: alias, openbox, autostart

I'm using two commands in a file executed by my `.config/openbox/autostart.sh` which are also aliased in my `.bash_alises` and one of them changes from time to time. The thing is that I also use these commands aliases in my `.bash_aliases` and changing all files with every change in every same way is quite annoying.
I'd like to have my aliases been known by the Openbox autostart file.

### My `.config/openbox/autostart.sh` (mainly)

```bash
. $GLOBALAUTOSTART
lxterminal -e "$(cat ~/.config/openbox/terminal.sh)" # command for a clean autostart file
```

### My `.config/openbox/terminal.sh`

```bash
a="b"

while [[ -n "$a" ]]; do
        read a
        if [[ "$a" =~ "o" ]] || [[ "$a" =~ "O" ]]; then
                sudo mount -t davfs example.com/webdav ~/exampleCom
                rsync -giloprtu --specials exampleCom/dir0/ dirs/directory_0
                rsync -giloprtu --specials exampleCom/dir1/ dirs/directory_1
                sudo umount exampleCom
        fi
[…]
done
```

### My `.bash_aliases`

```bash
alias RS='rsync -giloprtu --specials'
alias RSYNC='sudo mount -t davfs example.com/webdav ~/exampleCom
RS exampleCom/dir0/ dirs/directory_0
RS exampleCom/dir1/ dirs/directory_1
sudo umount exampleCom'
```

### Desired `.config/openbox/terminal.sh`

```bash
a="b"

while [[ -n "$a" ]]; do
        read a
        if [[ "$a" =~ "o" ]] || [[ "$a" =~ "O" ]]; then
                RSYNC # read from my ~/.bash_aliases
        fi
[…]
done
```

Comment: Aliases aren't expanded by default in non-interactive shells - consider using *shell functions* instead

Comment: @steeldriver How would I include the `.bash_functions` file, where the shell function `RSYNC` is written into if needed to do so?

Comment: You would [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source) it - `. "$HOME/.bash_functions"` or (with existence checking) `if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_functions" ]; then . "$HOME/.bash_functions"; fi`